# Lucky tag scores

Tags: discussion, answers, tag-score

While I agree that quality is more important than quantity, there is an element of a lucky answer which attracts a high number of votes, possibly as it gets a high rank on a search engine.

For example, in the [jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm) tag I have answered 272 questions which were upvoted (and about 100 more which were not)  However above me is a person who only answered one [jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm) question ever (one which would have been easily googled).

This might encourage new contributors to try their luck, but discourage new regular contributors who have less chance of reaching the top list.

Is there alternative scoring strategies being considered?

Comment: I'm reading "lucky" as "early in the site's history".  Not just that, but this *particular* answer has come up so often when dealing with different versions of Java, and is very well written.  I think it stands to the quality of the question and answer that this particular person is able to have such a high tag score.  You don't see those sorts of things *often*, though.  I suppose my rambling leads to this more broad question:  what makes them less deserving of a spot on the top list?

Comment: @Makoto "Early in the site's history" would be at least 5 years old IMO. That answer is less than 3.

Comment: Pretty sure no alternative is being considered.  Kinda hard to come up with one, be sure the mention what you were thinking of.  Right now it is just a lottery, play often enough and you'll get a winning ticket too some day.  Looks like you got one 7 times already, not too shabby :)

Comment: @HansPassant I am not so worried about my score but I do think it is odd the 3 of the top 20 only answered one question.

Comment: This situation drives the following behaviour: If someone is concerned about tag score, they won't answer questions by people with low rep, because they can't upvote. Why waste time for no reward? If they're not total jerks, they'll put a short answer in a comment. And who can blame them? . . . I'd like to see some way to better recognize the unsung heroes with tag score, rather than shiny badges!

Comment: @Mogsdad Nah, putting answers in comments is absolutely useless and as jerky, and actually obstructs the creation of proper answers as answers.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu ? Not sure what the 'nah' is directed at, since I didn't ask a yes/no question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Mogsdad Sure, sorry.. I had written a longer comment but shortened it due to not wanting to steal anyone's time. I was talking about the part of your comment where you hope that "they'll put a short answer in a comment", "if they're not total jerks". I'm formally disagreeing with the notion that this makes them less a jerk, because $(personal experience on SO). :) It's better for the asker, but worse for SO as a system. The 'nah' was hence directed at just that part of your comment, and I do apologize for somewhat derailing the (dead) conversation to a minor side topic. Have a good day!